# Remove Newsletter unsubscribe from left

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, theme, newsletter

I'm not able to find where to remove the "Newsletter unsubscribe" box on the left col.

You can find this here: http://outlet.redmouse.at/index.php/aussen.html

On the left there is this newsletter box.

**Where can I remove this?**

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the native newsletter block from Magento here.

### Removing it

In `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml` under the `<default>` node you can add:

```
<remove name="left.newsletter" />
```

### Moving it somewhere else

Still in the same file:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.newsletter</name></action>
</reference>

<reference name="target.block.name">
    <action method="insert"><block>left.newsletter</block></action>
</reference>
```